# React button not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, state

Hi everyone I'm building a simple waitlist page in React. In the Hero section, i've created a heading with an H1 and a form. The input form is working perfectly, the css is being activated when I focus and the state is being managed correctly. However, for some reason, the react button in the form is not clickable. Can anyone please advise?

```
import React from 'react'
import './Hero.css'
import prlearn_logo from '../assets/prlearn_logo.png'
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


function Hero(){

    //managing state of input field
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/c440c559-1f29-430e-9662-660693fecbbd,input')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="heading">
                <img className ="logo" src={prlearn_logo} alt="prlearn_logo" />
                <h1 className="h1">Learn Spanish from native speakers and support the local community.
                <br/> 
                <span>Feel at home by removing the language barrier.</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div className="waitlist">
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        className="input-field"
                        placeholder="Enter email address"
                        required
                        value={input}
                        //changes input in state function
                        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" className="button">Join The Waitlist</button>
                </form>
            </div>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hero
```

Answer (score 0):

Button is working correctly there is a typo in your code. While calling the Api you are making request to the wrong url. Instead of making request to this:>

```
axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/c440c559-1f29-430e-9662-660693fecbbd,input')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
```

Try this

```
axios
.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/c440c559-1f29-430e-9662- 
          660693fecbbd')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
```